# Tracing HTTP Request to Lambda Function Invocation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The frontend developers at my company want to be able to see the lambda function logs of their requests.

Is there a way to pass something like a user created unique id in a header in an http request that will be passed from api gateway to the lambda function so that it easy to find the logs for that particular request?

It is an environment where there could be many requests happening simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway will attach a unique ID to each request and this will filter through into Lambda. Each request should return a header with its response `x-amzn-RequestId` containing the request ID. In Lambda, you can access this request ID through the `context` object.

You're also free to create your own headers, `x-correlation-id` for example. In Lambda, you can access this header via the event.

Once you have you're value, you can attach that to your logs, directly as part of the log message or as metadata — depending on what logger you're using. If you're using CloudWatch, you might want to construct an object:

```
{ "requestId": "abc", "message": "This is a log entry." }
```

However you choose to do it, you should end up with a correlation ID which you can use to query your log entries.